# Do not repeat the same value as a regex

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to extract emails from a website with **Regex**.

The problem I am facing is that the emails are repeated, and I would not like that to happen. I tried to make several modifications with arrays and etc., but I was not successful.

I'm using the following website to take the test: https://5fce6d7a523d4.htmlsave.net/
Using the code below, the email "**jack@yopmail**" is repeated three times, I wanted it to be written only once on the console. Does anyone know how to do this?

```cs
    Regex Reg = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z0-9_\-\+]+@[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.([A-Za-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    string data;
    using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
    data = web.DownloadString("https://5fce6d7a523d4.htmlsave.net/");
    if (Reg.IsMatch(data))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Email Found");
        MatchCollection matches = Reg.Matches(data);
        foreach (Match math in matches)
            Console.WriteLine(math.Value);
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Email not found");
```

Comment: You could use named [groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group?view=net-5.0) and then check the occurrence count of a group (Captures property).

Comment: Do you have to do it with regex? By that I mean: if the endgoal is to print unique emails why not use a simple regex to get all the email addresses, and then use something like `Reg.Matches(data).Distinct()` to get the unique occurrences.

Comment: you can use linq, matches.Select(i=>i.Value).Distinct(), then just iterate through IEnumerable<string>

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this to retrieve unique emails from page, this also ignore cases and trims the value from match for unqiueness.

```
  Regex reg =
            new Regex(@"[A-Za-z0-9_\-\+]+@[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.([A-Za-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        string data;
        using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
            data = web.DownloadString("https://5fce6d7a523d4.htmlsave.net/");

        var resultList = reg.Matches(data)
            .Select(x=>x.ToString().ToLower().Trim())
            .Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            string input =
                "fat@gmail.com\n" +
                "jack@yopmail.com\n" +
                "richard444@outlook.com\n" +

                "You can contact me at jack@yopmail.com. This is my main email.\n" +
                "Email: jack@yopmail.com\n";

            string pattern = @"(?'email'[^\s]+@.+.com)";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
            string[] uniqueEmails = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["email"].Value).Distinct().ToArray();
```